# Hide Div based on button click asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a asp.net page where on page load im hiding a div untill a button is pressed. however my issue now is that i want to re hide the div based on another button that is within a modal , this button is to act as a reset button.

On the button that i want to hide the div i have

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_reset" runat="server" Text="Add Meter" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" OnClick ="reset_click" />
```

and in the aspx page i have

```
protected void reset_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Test.Visible = false;
}
```

Also within the div i have

```
<div id="Test" visible="false" runat="server">
```

If possible i would like to just reload the whole page so it defaults back to a fresh load.

Comment: If you want to refresh the whole page you can just use a link to the same url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you are looking for, but let's start off here:

[Live Preview](https://paymaster.com/other/test/asp1/)

**Code Behind:**

```
Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    pnlDiv1.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
    pnlDiv1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnShow" Text="SHOW" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnReset" Text="RESET" runat="server" />

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDiv1" Visible="false" runat="server">
        <h1>Im Hidden by Default</h1>
    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```